# How to make IntelliSense work correctly when using exports in package.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, vite, package.json

I have a package.json where I export different scripts using the exports field:

```
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "default": "./dist/main.es.js",
      "import": "./dist/main.es.js",
      "node": "./dist/main.cjs.js",
      "types": "./dist/main.d.ts"
    },
    "./models": {
      "default": "./dist/models/index.es.js",
      "import": "./dist/models/index.es.js",
      "node": "./dist/models/index.cjs.js",
      "types": "./dist/models/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./validators": {
      "default": "./dist/validators/index.es.js",
      "import": "./dist/validators/index.es.js",
      "node": "./dist/validators/index.cjs.js",
      "types": "./dist/validators/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
```

Everything is working fine and build succeeded but when I use the package in different projects the import mechanism differes

For example:

1. When I use it in similar project (TS project) with same tsconfig file it gives me the desired output

   [image]
2. When I use it within another TS project it conflicts with tsconfig options
   Because of node resolution option (in Application is **node** and the package is **bundler**)

   [image]
3. When I use it within Node.js (JS project based) it can't infer paths as expected

   [image]

So how can I adjust the configuration to work correctly ?

[Repo Link](https://github.com/MohammedSaberMohammed/vite-vanilla-ts-template/tree/main)